# RF6886 high power amplifier maximum reverse power

Tags: electronics, amplifier, impedance

I'm designing a circuit which uses the RF6886 amplifier IC. What is the maximum reverse power that the amplifier can sustain? At what reverse power will the amplifier die?

Answer (score 3):

[The datasheet](http://www.rfmd.com/store/downloads/dl/file/id/29775/rf6886_data_sheet.pdf) has an interesting table on page 5, which lists VSWR 5:1 for most frequencies, and 3.5:1 for some frequencies.

You can [calculate return power from VSWR](http://www.antenna-theory.com/definitions/vswr-calculator.php).

- VSWR 5:1 would 44.4444% of return power.
- At a maximum of 34 dBm (which is about 2.5 watts), the maximum return power would be 1.1 watts (at VSWR 5:1).

However, it is stated as "survival", so you will have to be more careful then that. Either build a protection circuit, or simply match properly.

Comment: Please don't add “signatures” to the ends of your posts. If you'd like to display your callsign, you can put it in your “display name” in your profile like I do, or in the “about me” section. (And thanks for writing a detailed answer with examples and links!)

Answer (score 0):

You have, at least, 3 alternatives:

- Read the datasheet. They mention SWR 5:1
- Empirical research: Increase the SWR until smoke.
- Avoid. Use a matchbox.